# Links in email from SE are weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, contact, url-encoding

I contacted SE using the contact page recently. I got a reply.

[This was a part of the reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V73vd.png):

> Typically, the fastest way to address this sort of problem is to [raise a flag](https://%7B%7Bdomain%7D%7D/help/flagging) on the post or comment (note that flagging requires [a bit of reputation](https://%7B%7Bdomain%7D%7D/help/privileges/flag-posts)).

As you can notice, the links are weird. Clicking them don't work. I noticed that the URLs were weird.

I logged-in in https://support.stackenterprise.co/ and the links were weird there as well.

Please fix this issue.

Comment: `{{domain}}` - URL encoding and interpolation failed.

Comment: This led to a [Firefox bug report](//bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1746494) and another bug report for a [web extension](//github.com/Drive4ik/simple-tab-groups/issues/899). Those pesky malformed URLs create some subtle trouble. Thanks for unintentionally raising awareness about them!

Answer (score 11):

We are currently using another platform for technical support so it may explain the issue.

All our responses have now been updated.